# Docker: how to open ports to the host machine?

Tags: docker

What could be the reason for Docker containers not being able to connect via ports to the host system?

Specifically, I'm trying to connect to a MySQL server that is running on the Docker host machine (`172.17.0.1` on the Docker bridge). However, for some reason port `3306` is always closed.

The steps to reproduce are pretty simple:

1. Configure MySQL (or any service) to listen on `0.0.0.0` (`bind-address=0.0.0.0` in `~/.my.cnf`)
2. run

   ```
   $ docker run -it alpine sh
   # apk add --update nmap
   # nmap -p 3306 172.17.0.1
   ```

That's it. No matter what I do it will always show

```
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
3306/tcp closed mysql
```

I've tried the same with an ubuntu image, a Windows host machine, and other ports as well.

I'd like to avoid `--net=host` if possible, simply to make proper use of containerization.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24326540/645002 It's very thorough, should get you where you need to be

Comment: @Frap Yep, that's a great answer and also where I got most of the info on how to use the bridge mode and get the host IP address etc. But unfortunately it didn't help with this issue.

Comment: Without totally borking the auto-bridge setup by docker (assuming you are not an iptables masochist), and excluding --net=host.....      Pass in a custom dns entry for the host via --add-host.

Comment: You'll need to do a bit more troubleshooting I guess. Can you at least access your MySQL instance _from the host_ on either 127.0.0.1 or 172.17.0.1?

Comment: @mustaccio Both work, yep. I can run several services on the host machine and connect to them successfully from the host itself.

Comment: Another day, currently on Windows: it appears `route` in the container does not return the host's IP address. It returns `172.17.0.1` while `ipconfig` on the host returns `10.0.75.1`. `nmap` within the container to `10.0.75.1` returns `open` and my MySQL client app works fine. On `172.17.0.1` it still says `closed`. Any idea what's up with those IPs? Is there a way to query the working IP programmatically from within the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the IPs weren't correct. There was nothing blocking the ports and the services were running fine too. `ping` and `nmap` showed the IP as online but for some reason it wasn't the host system.

Lesson learned: don't rely on `route` in the container to return the correct host address. Instead check `ifconfig` or `ipconfig` on the Linux or Windows host respectively and pass this IP via environment variables.

Right now I'm transitioning to using `docker-compose` and have put all required services into containers, so the host system doesn't need to get involved and I can simply rely on Docker's DNS. This is much more satisfying.